# Creating a list with zip()

Tags: python, python-zip

I'm trying to understand why when my code look like this:

```
x_coord = [23, 53, 2, -12, 95, 103, 14, -5]
y_coord = [677, 233, 405, 433, 905, 376, 432, 445]
z_coord = [4, 16, -6, -42, 3, -6, 23, -1]
labels = ["F", "J", "A", "Q", "Y", "B", "W", "X"]
points=[]
for point in zip(labels, x_coord,y_coord, z_coord):
    points = points.append(point)
```

I get the error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

But when I do this:

```
x_coord = [23, 53, 2, -12, 95, 103, 14, -5]
y_coord = [677, 233, 405, 433, 905, 376, 432, 445]
z_coord = [4, 16, -6, -42, 3, -6, 23, -1]
labels = ["F", "J", "A", "Q", "Y", "B", "W", "X"]
points=[]
for point in zip(labels, x_coord,y_coord, z_coord):
    points.append(point)
```

It works , theres is something wrong with the syntaxis? , I mean points is define as a list and list has the append method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `points.append(point)` is a method and doesn't return a value, hence when you do `points = points.append(point)`, `points` takes the (lack of a) return value and becomes `None` (you overwrote the `list` type with `None` type).

However, when you do `point.append(point)`, you are correctly adding elements to the list by calling its built-in method, and not overwriting anything, which is why the second code works but not the first.

Comment: Well , it's clear now and yes I'm learning, thanks for the answer.

Comment: That's good to hear! Feel free to upvote/accept answer(s) that helped you!

Answer (score 1):

`append` is a method on list and doesn't return anything (so returns `None` object). Thus `points` is set to `None` after the first iteration.

By the way, there's no need to iterate:

```py
points = list(zip(labels, x_coord,y_coord, z_coord))
```

Answer (score 0):

With `points=points.append(point)`, you actually assign a `NoneType Object` instead of list since `points.append(point)` return `None`. So, assigning `points=points.append(point)` destroys your list.

Answer (score 0):

In your first code, after the first iteration of the loop, `points` gets assigned the return value or `.append()`, which does not return anything.

If you wanted to use the assignment statement to add to a list you could do `points[len(points):len(points)] = [point]`.